# kali-linuxでpip install github3を実行するとエラーになる。

Tags: linux, pip

Kali-Linux-2020.2-vmware-i386
Python: Python 2.7.18
pip: 20.0.2

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python /usr/share/python-wheels/pep517-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpvBlHwf                                                                         
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-CfqFDZ/cryptography                           
  Complete output (1 lines):                                               
  /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/usr/share/python-wheels/pep517-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pep517/_in_process.py'                 
  ----------------------------------------                                 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python /usr/share/python-wheels/pep517-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpvBlHwf Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

kali linux の　python2 のpip は終了しています。

セキュリティー関係の本には　python2 の　pip2でgithub3を
ビルドできると書いてありますが、
今年　python2のサポート」は終了しましたので
pip2は使えないと思います。

python2はpython3のpip3に集積しているらしいです

python3のプログラミングで組んであるもので、pip3でgithub3をbildできる
のを作成しなければならないと思います。